# How to implement a hold button down function on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a button that does different things depending on the time you hold it down, then you release it.

```js
var presstime;

function meter(elm) {
  power = setInterval(function() {
    if (presstime > 99) {
      clearInterval(power);
      document.getElementById(elm).classList.add('full');
    } else {
      presstime = parseInt(presstime) + 10;
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<span onmousedown="meter('gauge');" onmouseup="dothings('thing1',presstime);">Execute</span>
```

This works fine on a PC but not so on mobile devices because when you hold the button down with your finger all it does is zooming in or so depending on the browser. How can I override that?

Comment: You did not define `presstime`. Also, have you tried [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) i.e. `touchstart`, `touchend`, etc...?

Comment: I was in the middle of doing that when you edited my post.

Comment: [Try this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=press+hold+javascript+mobile+site:stackoverflow.com)